# some code which extends applet

Tags: java, applet

this is my code (sorry for putting this) really I need your help would you please help me that how can I remove applet from this(init method)I don't like use applet also I am beginner I have done something but it doesn't make it OK. thanks

```
  public class RedGreenGriffin extends Applet {

    protected Canvas3D c1 = new Canvas3D(SimpleUniverse.getPreferredConfiguration());
   // private Canvas3D c2 = new Canvas3D(SimpleUniverse.getPreferredConfiguration());
    private static MainFrame mf;
    protected SimpleUniverse u = null;
    protected BranchGroup scene = null;
    protected String URLString = "http://www.java3d.org/saurus.obj";
    protected float eyeOffset =0.03F;
    protected static int size=600;
    public void init() {
        setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        GraphicsConfiguration config =
           SimpleUniverse.getPreferredConfiguration();
        String v = getParameter("url");
        if (v != null) { URLString = v; }
        c1.setSize(size, size);
        add(c1);
        scene = createSceneGraph(0);
        u = new SimpleUniverse(c1);
        // This will move the ViewPlatform back a bit so the
        // objects in the scene can be viewed.
        //u.getViewingPlatform().setNominalViewingTransform();
        u.addBranchGraph(scene);

    }
public BranchGroup createSceneGraph(int i) {
    System.out.println("Creating scene for: "+URLString);
    // Create the root of the branch graph
    BranchGroup objRoot = new BranchGroup();
    try{
        Transform3D myTransform3D = new Transform3D();
        myTransform3D.setTranslation(new Vector3f(+0.0f,-0.15f,-3.6f));
        TransformGroup objTrans = new TransformGroup(myTransform3D);
        objTrans.setCapability(TransformGroup.ALLOW_TRANSFORM_WRITE);
        Transform3D t = new Transform3D();
        TransformGroup tg = new TransformGroup(t);
        tg.setCapability(TransformGroup.ALLOW_TRANSFORM_READ);
        tg.setCapability(TransformGroup.ALLOW_TRANSFORM_WRITE);
        objTrans.addChild(tg);
        URL url = new URL(URLString) ;
        ObjectFile f = new ObjectFile();
        f.setFlags(ObjectFile.RESIZE | ObjectFile.TRIANGULATE | ObjectFile.STRIPIFY);
        System.out.println( "About to load" );

        Scene s = f.load(url);
        Transform3D myTrans = new Transform3D();
        myTrans.setTranslation(new Vector3f(eyeOffset, -eyeOffset, 0F));
        TransformGroup mytg = new TransformGroup(myTrans);
        //mytg.addChild(s.getSceneGroup());
        tg.addChild(mytg);
        Transform3D myTrans2 = new Transform3D();
        myTrans2.setTranslation(new Vector3f(-eyeOffset, +eyeOffset, 0F));
        TransformGroup mytg2 = new TransformGroup(myTrans2);
        //mytg2.addChild(s.getSceneGroup());
        Hashtable table = s.getNamedObjects();
        for (Enumeration e = table.keys() ; e.hasMoreElements() ;) {
        Object key = e.nextElement();
        System.out.println(key);
        Object obj = table.get(key);
        System.out.println(obj.getClass().getName());
        Shape3D shape  = (Shape3D)obj;
        //shape.setCapability(Shape3D.ALLOW_APPEARANCE_WRITE);
        Appearance ap = new Appearance();
        Color3f black = new Color3f(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
        Color3f red = new Color3f(0.7f, .0f, .15f);
        Color3f green = new Color3f(0f, .7f, .15f);
        ap.setMaterial(new Material(green,black, green, black, 1.0f));
        Appearance ap2 = new Appearance();
        ap2.setMaterial(new Material(red, black, red, black, 1.0f));
        float transparencyValue = 0.5f;
        TransparencyAttributes t_attr =
            new TransparencyAttributes(
            TransparencyAttributes.BLENDED,
            transparencyValue,
            TransparencyAttributes.BLEND_SRC_ALPHA,
            TransparencyAttributes.BLEND_ONE);
        ap2.setTransparencyAttributes( t_attr );
        ap2.setRenderingAttributes( new RenderingAttributes() );
        ap.setTransparencyAttributes( t_attr );
        ap.setRenderingAttributes( new RenderingAttributes() );
        // bg.addChild(ap);
        shape.setAppearance(ap);
        mytg2.addChild(new Shape3D(shape.getGeometry(),ap2));
        mytg.addChild(new Shape3D(shape.getGeometry(),ap));
    }
    tg.addChild(mytg2);
    System.out.println( "Finished Loading" );
    BoundingSphere bounds =
        new BoundingSphere(new Point3d(0.0,0.0,0.0), 100.0);
    Color3f light1Color = new Color3f(.9f, 0.9f, 0.9f);
    Vector3f light1Direction  = new Vector3f(4.0f, -7.0f, -12.0f);
    DirectionalLight light1
    = new DirectionalLight(light1Color, light1Direction);
    light1.setInfluencingBounds(bounds);
    objTrans.addChild(light1);
            // Set up the ambient light
    Color3f ambientColor = new Color3f(1.0f, .4f, 0.3f);
    AmbientLight ambientLightNode = new AmbientLight(ambientColor);
    ambientLightNode.setInfluencingBounds(bounds);
    objTrans.addChild(ambientLightNode);


    MouseRotate behavior = new MouseRotate();
    behavior.setTransformGroup(tg);
    objTrans.addChild(behavior);
      // Create the translate behavior node
    MouseTranslate behavior3 = new MouseTranslate();
    behavior3.setTransformGroup(tg);
    objTrans.addChild(behavior3);
    behavior3.setSchedulingBounds(bounds);

    KeyNavigatorBehavior keyNavBeh = new KeyNavigatorBehavior(tg);
    keyNavBeh.setSchedulingBounds(new BoundingSphere(
        new Point3d(),1000.0));
    objTrans.addChild(keyNavBeh);

    behavior.setSchedulingBounds(bounds);
    objRoot.addChild(objTrans);
    } catch(Throwable t){System.out.println("Error: "+t);}
    return objRoot;
}
public RedGreenGriffin() {
}
public void destroy() {
    u.removeAllLocales();
}

public static void main(String[] args) {

    RedGreenGriffin s = new RedGreenGriffin();
    if (args.length > 0) {
        s.URLString = args[0];
    }
    mf = new MainFrame(s, size, size);
}
}
```

Comment: So you're goal is for this to no longer be an applet... ?

Comment: yes ,I don't want it to be an applet

Answer (score 0):

If you want to build a standalone GUI application in Swing, you should put your content into a `JFrame` rather than an `Applet`.

There are other GUI frameworks you could use to build a standalone Java GUI application, but Swing is the most popular, and it's the one for which you'll probably be able to find the most helpful documentation (including here on Stack Overflow :-) ).

Comment: so I should delete "extends applet" and use "extends JFrame" ?

Answer (score 0):

I'd start by changing the `extends Applet` to `extends JFrame`

However, a `JFrame` doesn't need or use a `public void init()` method, so you'll want to move that code somewhere else.
With only the goal of making this a GUI program, my suggestion is to either:

- rename your `init()` method to `frameInit()`
- ... or just move the code in `init()` into the constructor.